# GeoIP package for tcl or alternative

Tags: tcl, geoip

In the past there was a geoIP package for tcl available according to:

http://wiki.tcl.tk/16195

Does anyone still have it or can recommend an alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this wiki post that pre-dates the one you referenced: http://wiki.tcl.tk/12521.  It says it "needs Maxmind CVS (sic) database available here" but unlike the MaxMind url referenced in the wiki url you posted, the link to the csv file still works.

Comment: Ugh; the linked code says “CVS” even though it should be “CSV”…

Answer (score 0):

TCL bindings for libGeoIP [are available from Debian](http://packages.debian.org/source/sid/tclgeoip). This should work with the binary databases. I believe this is the same library that was previously distributed by MaxMind.